# How to find the number of non null items in a char array. C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am doing a project for my computer science one course and I am having trouble trying to get the exact size of an array that contains char values. First off the program prompts the user to enter the char values, by using the line `cin.getline(array,100);` Afterwards, it takes the array and then passes it a getSize function that is suppose to return the actual size of the array. The only problem is that it is not inconsistent. Sometimes it returns the right value, but other times it doesn't. 
getSize function :

```
int getSize(char arr[]){
    int i = 0;  
    for(i; '\0' != arr[i];i++){ 
    }
    return i;
}
```

Example: 
arr[100] contains 5 characters and the rest are null, but the function returns 7 when the program runs. I am not sure if this is an issue, but the program modifies the array before sending it to the size function. It removes the duplicates.

Comment: Can you give an example on the case where it is inconsistent?

Comment: Can you show the inconsistency in results.?

Comment: i think it is a bit confusing because when you say size you actually mean number of non-zero elements or length of the string in this case.

Comment: Yeah your right. I re worded the title.

Comment: why don't you use strlen function?

Comment: So, if a `char arr[10]` has non-zero elements in slots 1, 3, 5, 7, and 9, and the rest are zero, what do you *expect* is the return value? Is it 1 (i.e. the length of a C string starting at `arr[0]`), or is it 5 (the number of non-zero elements in the 10-slot array? *What do you want*?

Comment: I've reread your question several times now, and am now convinced all you need is `strlen()`. Also, you're sample data result is wrong. It is *impossible* to arrange *only* five non-zero characters in an array of longer-than-5 chars, have the rest be zero, and have the algorithm you're showing report greater than 5. Even if all five non-zero char values were at the beginning of the array, your loop terminates with `i=5`, and thusly reports said-same. v2c.

Comment: @user2940061 do you really want the number of non-zero chars in the arrary? your example suggests otherwise

Answer (score 4):

Since you're dealing with arrays, use the strlen function

```
strlen(array);
```

Note that there's also a getline [overload for strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) that's more C++ like (object oriented etc)

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
size_t len = line.length();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template<size_t t_size>
size_t GetRealSize(const char (&str)[t_size])
{
    return std::count_if(&str[0], &str[t_size], [](char c) { return !!c; });
}
```

This might be what you want.

Comment: He wants the size of the line returned

Comment: @nishantjr, my fault. I changed my original answer.

Comment: So far this is the only answer that fits the actual letter of the specific question, but I'm not convinced the OP even knows what was asked, or what they even *want* at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with pointers alone. Pointers contain no information about the size of the array - they are only a memory address. Because arrays decay to pointers when passed to a function, you lose the size of the array.

One way is to use `Templates`

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t array(const T (&buffer)[N])
{
cout << "size: " << N << endl;
return N;
}
```

You can then call the function like this (just like any other function):

```
int main()
{
char a[10];
array(a);
}
```

Output:

```
size: 10
```

Comment: I would use that, but I don't think I am suppose to know about templates and pointer yet..

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use `sizeof()` operator to get size,...

if you have `char a[10];`

use

```
int size=sizeof(a);
```

Comment: now do that with `a` as a function parameter to a function called `int getSize( char a[] )`.

Comment: The OP is is trying to get this from a function taking the array as a single input-parameter. this isn't that, so *why* try something that doesn't fit the question to begin with?

Comment: Loop until.... a NUL-terminator? Thats `strlen()`. After 40 minutes the question still isn't posted clearly, but one thing is: it is from a function parameter.

Comment: y should you need the function for if you have size of.. i mean is your array declared as 
char a[100];?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40292/discussion-between-raon-and-whozcraig)